What is the difference/precedence of resolved.conf and a .network configuration?
There are two places where I can set up the DNS server for a systemd linux (static configuration):

in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, in the [Resolve] section, a DNS= entry
in /etc/systemd/network/<interface>.network, in the [Network] section, a DNS= entry

Which one takes precedence?

The link settings (second bullet) seem to take over per the resolved.conf documentation:

Without the Domains=~. option in resolved.conf(5), systemd-resolved might use the per-link DNS servers, if any of them set Domains=~. in the per-link configuration.

